# Unexpected extract value from json structure in python

Tags: python, json

I am try to use python to extract value, but I found a weird result. 
Following is part of my json variable

```
"weatherElement": [
 {
  "elementName": "ELEV",
  "elementValue": {
   "value": "20.0"
  }
 },
 {
  "elementName": "TEMP",
  "elementValue": {
   "value": "25.0"
  }
 },
 {
  "elementName": "D_TNT",
  "elementValue": {
   "value": "2019-11-22T02:10:00+08:00"
  }
 }
],
```

and following code is correct for getting value 25.0 which is temperature

```
for unit in data['records']['location']:
    # print(type(unit))  <---- output <dict>
    if unit['stationId'] == 'C0V490':
        for wea_unit in unit['weatherElement']: # unit['weatherElement'] is list
            if wea_unit['elementName'] == 'TEMP':
                print(type(wea_unit['elementValue'])) # is str
                return wea_unit['elementValue']
```

My question is why `type(wea_unit['elementValue'])` is `str`?

I think it should be `dict` and I should use `wea_unit['elementValue']['value']` to get '25.0', but it is wrong. Are there anyone know what mistake I made? Thanks!

edit:

following is example code which can run directly

```
import json
def parse_json_to_dataframe(data):
    for unit in data['records']['location']:
        # print(type(unit))
        if unit['stationId'] == 'C0A560':
            for wea_unit in unit['weatherElement']: # unit['weatherElement'] is list
                if wea_unit['elementName'] == 'TEMP':
                    print(type(wea_unit['elementValue']))
                    return wea_unit['elementValue']
v = {"success":"true",
"result": {"resource_id": "O-A0001-001", 
"fields": [{"id": "lat", "type": "Double"},
{"id": "lon", "type": "Double"}, 
{"id": "locationName", "type": "String"}, 
{"id": "stationId", "type": "String"}, 
{"id": "description", "type": "String"}, 
{"id": "elementName", "type": "String"}, 
{"id": "elementValue", "type": "Double"}, 
{"id": "parameterName", "type": "String"}, 
{"id": "parameterValue", "type": "String"}]}, # result end
"records": {"location": [{"lat": "24.778333", 
"lon": "121.494583",
"locationName": "福山", 
"stationId": "C0A560", 
"time": {"obsTime": "2019-11-22 22:00:00"}, 
"weatherElement": [
{"elementName": "ELEV", "elementValue": "405.0"}, 
{"elementName": "WDIR", "elementValue": "0"}, 
{"elementName": "WDSD", "elementValue": "0.0"}, 
{"elementName": "TEMP", "elementValue": "19.6"}], 
"parameter": [
{"parameterName": "CITY_SN", "parameterValue": "06"}, 
{"parameterName": "TOWN_SN", "parameterValue": "061"}]}]}}
temp = parse_json_to_dataframe(v)
print(temp)
```

Comment: it gives me that it's dict!, maybe the you didn't parse the string you have, follow the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: @Ghanem I doubt that would be the issue, since the code would error out on `data['records']['location']` already.  OP, please create a [mre] as right now it doesn't seem reproducible.  Also, what are you getting in `return`?

Comment: @r.ook , I meant maybe the last part inside "elementValue".

Comment: @Ghanem I get 25.0 for return value

Comment: @Ghanem Based on the data provided `elementValue` is definitely a `dict` though.  The entire data was either taken in as a string (would fail at the aforementioned spot) or `type(wea_unit['elementValue'])` would return `dict`, it can't be half string and half parsed.  Unless, OP has an `elementValue` besides the shown data that is actually a `str`.

Comment: Actually, the json variable I gave is partial.

Comment: @Steven then you have an actual `str` type in there somewhere within `elementValue`.  And it will raise an error if you try to retrieve `wea_unit['elementValue']['value']` at that iteration.  Again, creating a [mre] would help both you and us step through the problem.

Comment: @r.ook hey, I just update an example code which can run directly. Hope you can give me some suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @Steven , the first json file you provide us is different than the last one. In the first one `elementValue` is dict you're right `"elementValue": {"value": "25.0"}`, but not in the second one. `{"elementName": "TEMP", "elementValue": "19.6"}`

Comment: Your new sample is showing that `elementValue` is indeed a `str` type. The code is running exactly as it's expected to.  If you wanted to use it as a float value, do `float(wea_unit['elementValue'])`

Comment: yes, I finally found both examples are different, first one is got from .json, and last one is get from python `.json()` method. So it seems like python transfer `elementValue": {"value": "25.0"}` to `{"elementName": "TEMP", "elementValue": "19.6"}` right?